# How to download an image File and save into local hard drive using AngularJS by calling Web Services

Tags: ajax, angularjs, web-services, rest

My Requirement is

1. In web application if I click a download link, a REST web service call is be made.
2. Response of the Web Service  is byte[] and Content-Disposition=[attachment;]
3. Saving the response into local drive by popping up a dialogue box.

I have tried with ajax call and successfully getting byte[] response, but can't save into local hard drive. The code snippet is below.

HTML code is

```
<div data-ng-app="myApp"  data-ng-controller="myCtrl" >
  <a href="#" data-ng-click="downloadImage()">download</a>
</di>
```

Angular Script is

```
   angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, $http){

     $scope.downloadImage= function (){     
           var responsePromise = $http.get(resourceUrl);

           responsePromise.success(function (data) {
              alert("File Stream:"+data);
           });

           responsePromise.error(function(data) {
             alert("AJAX failed! in downloading Image:"+ data);
           });
      }
    });
```

In alert, I am getting full stream as byte[]. I want to save into local hard disk. I understand that response is stored in browser memory, but how to redirect storing into local drive?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Should not we use ajax call for this? If not, what is the alternative approach?

Can anyone help me how to resolve this as it is my high priority.

Comment: You won't be able to launch a prompt for the user to select the location to save a file. The best you can do is tell the browser to download the file. Even if you do that, the user will have the option to just open it and it will be stored in a temp location.

Answer (score 2):

I used Blob and FileSaver to do this recently:

```
$http.get(url, {responseType:'blob'})
.then(function(results){
    var data = results.data; 
    var blob = new Blob(
        [data],
        {type: "image/png"}
    );
    saveAs(blob, "myFilename.png");
});
```

Note particularly the responseType config parameter to the $http.get method.

[Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob)

[FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)

[XMLHttpRequest#responseType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#responseType)

Hope that Helps.